# Ошибка в tcp-socket соединениях на nodejs

Tags: node.js

Подскажите, может кто знает. делаем игру для контакта. на nodejs есть tcp-сервер, который слушает соединения с flash. все работает, данные ходят туда-сюда. но через пару дней flash не может соединиться с nodejs. при этом процесс nodejs не отваливается, ошибки никакие не выдает. утечку памяти проверял с помощью memwatch, вроде тоже все нормально. обработчик onError стоит на tcp-сервере и на сокете, они также ошибок не ловят. может кто сталкивался с проблемой?

**Обновление**

http://pastebin.ru/fX4db5b7

Comment: телепатия здесь бессильна... давайте код.

Answer (score 1):

Проверяйте telnet есть ли вообще соединение, может у вас приложение уходит куда-то в бесконечный цикл и не может отвечать на запросы (сделайте coredump процесса и проверьте gdb чем оно там занималось, может и strace хватит впрочем). для проверки предположения, повесте setInterval на 1 минуту чтобы он в консоль что нить показывал (текущее время например) если перестанет показывать, значит куда-то повисает.

**Обновление**

`write_error('socket connection: ' + error);` вот это отрабатывает ? если нет, то вам светит дебаг, (`node debug -p pid` как вариант)

**Обновление 2**

Это не про ошибку, это должно вроде на каждое соединение срабатывать. А, сорри, наверное не оттуда посмотрел

```
socket.on('connect', function () {
    if(is_debug_mode)
        write_log('socket connect');
});
```

Вот это срабатывает? В общем debug так бессмысленно гадать.

Comment: имеете в виду проверить есть ли вообще соединение, когда nodejs перестает отвечать на запросы от flash?

Comment: Нет, в том то и дело, что ни одной ошибки nodejs не выдает

Comment: ага, срабатывает, все работает как надо пару-тройку дней. а дебагом ведь можно удаленно пользоваться?

Answer (score 1):

Мое предложение - напишите на `c/python/perl/любой_другой_язык` тестового клиента. Запустите в локальной сети сервер и несколько сотен/тысяч клиентов. (В теории, это даже на одной машине можно сделать). Дозируя нагрузку, научитесь доводить до нужно состояния "зависания". А там и отлаживать будет просто.